# How to display only the path of corresponding command's man page?

Tags: command-line

I want to get the corresponding man page path for a particular command.

Is there any single command to display only the man page path for a particular command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man` has a `--where`/`-w` flag for this:

```
$ man -w ls
/usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz
```

From `man man`:

```
   -w, --where, --location
          Don't actually display the manual pages, but do print
          the location(s) of the source nroff files that  would
          be formatted.
```

Comment: oh, i forget to see that.